# Bad Request: unconfigured columnfamily <CF_name> in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am using following version of cql and cassandra. See below:
cqlsh 2.3.0 | Cassandra 1.1.10 | CQL spec 3.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.33.0

I have all CF and tons of data in it. When I run:

> cqlsh -2  or cqlsh -3 
>   cql> USE "test_keyspace"; 
>   cql:test_keyspace> SELECT * FROM "column_family_name" LIMIT 1;

Note: CFs were created using pycassa and am trying to read using cql. Not sure, if this will make a difference.

It throws, 
Bad Request: unconfigured columnfamily 
Perhaps you meant to use CQL 2? Try using the -2 option when starting cqlsh.

Is there any specific settings, that I need to be looking at, to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured, one solution is using nodetool cfstats options and evaluate the result. This works for CFs which were never used at all but not work for CFs which were created and used for sometime, never cleaned up and abandoned later as their is no access time for CF in nodetool cfstats result.

Answer (score 10):

by default CQL3 is case-insensitive unless enclosed in double quotation marks. Try putting your CFNAME in double quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM "CFNAME" LIMIT 1;
```

Looks like you have forgotten to enable CQL3 from api at the time of table creation

Comment: \@abhi - sorry about that but I am specifying CF name. OQ edited. I was using <CF> and editor removed it thinking it as a meta tag or something

Comment: can you share your DESCRIBE COLUMNFAMILIES information? use cqlsh

Comment: cqlsh:ks_prod> DESCRIBE COLUMNFAMILIES;           
                                                       
CFtest1                                CFtest2

Comment: by default CQL3 is case-insensitive unless enclosed in double quotation marks. See the update section

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying a keyspace in your statement.

Either specify the keyspace as follows:

```
 SELECT * FROM "keyspace_name"."column_family_name" LIMIT 1;
```

Or before querying the column family specify the keyspace to cqlsh via the 'using' statement:

```
using "keyspace_name"
```

Comment: Coming across tons of issues with cql 2/3 and cassandra 1.1.10 (CASSANDRA-4363). Moving onto pycassa. Thanks folks.

Comment: @CuriousMind cql is the future (thrift api wont be getting new features) but it's your choice. If you post some more details about your keyspace (how you create it etc.) i can post some examples on what you need to do. But anyway goodluck!

Comment: Column Families were created using pycassa as fas as I know. This is lagacy code. I am just trying to figure out all unused CFs, so I can drop them. Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: @CuriousMind What you could do is look at the timestamps of columns in the diffrent column families. The problem is that cql(sh) cant do that but if you use pycassa and add `include_timestamp=True` to the arguments for your `.get()` you'll be able to view timestamps. Then you can work out the last time that columns were used.